# How to write a regular expression for excluding some special characters from string?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to exclude the following characters from my string:

```
\--
'
<
>
```

Please tell me how to write a regular expression for this.

Comment: *Do Not Use A Regex*. Use a standard string manipulation function (faster and more suitable for the job)... for example in python, str.translate would do the job... in Java, String.replace ... use C#'s equivalent function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is how to remove `\--` and `'` and `<` and `>` from a string then this regex does the job:

```
['<>]|\\--
```

or in C#

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"['<>]|\\--", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd just use string.Replace.  Regular expressions are great, but should be used wisely.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex dialect supports lookaheads:

```
^(?:(?!\\--|['<>]).)*$
```

However, in some languages it might be cleaner to have a simple manual check rather than use a regex.

Comment: The range `--'` is invalid. At least in .NET's regex implementation.

Comment: Right you are. I just mechanically copied the characters, not even noticing there were two dashes. With your edit to the OP, it seems the whole sequence is to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = Regex.Replace(SomeString, "[\-'<>]", "");
```

Hope this helps.